# Composer com Bootstrap?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, composer

Como posso chamar o `bootstrap` utilizando o `composer`, tentei por algum tempo
mas infelizmente não consegui alguém tem alguma ideia?

Caminho do pasta vendor do `composer`

```
<?php  require "../../vendor/autoload.php";

?>
```

Código utilizando `Bootstrap`:

```
<html>
   <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div>
   <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">...</div>
   <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">...</div>
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">...</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Composer é um gerenciador de pacotes do PHP, já Bootstrap é uma biblioteca CSS. O que você tentou fazer não faz sentido. Basta adicionar os arquivos CSS na página com o elemento `link` e funcionará normalmente.

Comment: No site do bootstrap :http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/
tem a opção de instalar a biblioteca do bootstrap via composer e para a utilização seria necessário utilizar o require mencionado, porém, minha duvida é como utilizar.